# 1:05 for transfer at Manchester airport

Tags: uk, short-connections, man

I have just bought a ticket with a short time transfer at Manchester airport. The company is Fly Be. The first flight is from Edinburgh to Manchester, then the second flight to Paris. Will I make it?

Comment: This should be do-able if both flights are with Flybe. There are several flights from Manchester to Paris daily so if you do have a single booking and you don’t mind getting to Paris later than expected, I wouldn’t worry too much.

Comment: If they sold you the ticket, then they think the transfer is manageable - and its largely their problem if you don't make it.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the whole itinerary was bought as a single ticket from Fly Be, then:

- If they sold you the ticket, that means they think you can make it
- Your luggage will be transferred directly to your destination
- They are responsible for getting you to your destination if you don't (rebooking you on the next available flight)
- You are owed assistance if you are delayed
- You may even be owed compensation if you are delayed beyond a certain time and it's the airline's fault (which is pretty wide-ranging)

1 hour and 5 minutes for a domestic-to-EU transfer (so no passport control) in an airport of the size of Manchester really shouldn't be a problem if the incoming flight is on time. Don't know the layout at MAN, but you possibly won't even go through security again.

Apparently, there's another MAN-CDG flight after yours, so the chances you'll be stuck overnight if you miss the connection are pretty slim (unless that flight is fully booked).

Still, if you worry about it:

- Try to get a seat as close to the front of the plane as possible to minimise time to deplane.
- Look up the terminal map in advance, and check similar flights on previous days to see what gates are most probable for your flights
- Let staff know you have a short connection, especially if there's any indication of a delay. That includes check-in staff, gate staff and cabin crew. If the plane is delayed, they may be able to move you closer to the front, or get you out before other passengers.